# Как генерировать случайное byte число в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, случайные-числа

Почему обычный С# `Random` не работает в Unity-скрипте?
Пробую такой код для смены цветового канала по нажатию кнопки:

```
void Update () {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
        byte value = rnd.Next();
    }
    Color32 color32 = new Color32(4, 128, 192, value);
    obj.GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color = color32;
}
```

Также не пойму как задать интервал, в котором будет происходить генерация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `System.Random`:

Метод `Next()` возвращает `int` и нужно явное приведение к типу `byte`:

```
byte value = (byte)rnd.Next();
```

Или, на случай нежелания использовать приведение типов, вариант с методом `NextBytes`:

```
var buffer = new byte[1];
rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
byte value = buffer[0];
```

Интервал можно задать с помощью перегрузки метода `Next`, принимающей два `int` числа: `minValue` (включительно) и `maxValue` (не включительно).

---

Вариант, который должен бы сработать для `UnityEngine.Random`:

```
byte value = (byte)Random.Range(0, 256);
```

Comment: тоесть сначала генерировать в int, а потом конвертировать в byte? я правильно понял?

Comment: @Jonathan да. Равномерное распределение результата при этом должно сохраниться.

Comment: Пишет такую ошибку, на первую строку: Error CS1023: An embedded statement may not be a declaration or labeled statement (CS1023) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: И на NextByte: Error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `NextBytes' and no extension method `NextBytes' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: @Jonathan конечно такого метода нет. Учитывая что в вопросе вы написали, что используете обычный C#-ский `Random` (`System.Random`), а на деле, судя по тексту ошибки, используете `UnityEngine.Random`. Нехорошо вводить других в заблуждение. Добавлю в конец ответа вариант, который, возможно, сработает для `UnityEngine.Random`.

Comment: Да действительно моя ошибка, спасибо большое теперь все работает.